# audiotrack: playing noise for a raw pcm 16bit wav file

Tags: android, audio, pcm

I am trying to play a wav file of size 230mb and 20 min whose properties are as below:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.wav

Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

I am learning how to use audiotrack.

I found two solutions to play this audio play using audiotrack.

**Solution 1: the following plays the audio**

```
int frequency = 44100;
int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO;
int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration,audioEncoding);

AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, frequency,
        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize,
        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

int count = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
try{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(listMusicFiles.get(0).listmusicfiles_fullfilepath);
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
    audioTrack.play();

    while((count = dataInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) > -1){
        audioTrack.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    audioTrack.stop();
    audioTrack.release();
    dataInputStream.close();
    fileInputStream.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Second Solution: Playing noise**

```
int frequency = 44100;
int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO;
int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration,audioEncoding);

short[] audiodata = new short[bufferSize];

try {

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    listMusicFiles.get(0).listmusicfiles_fullfilepath)));

    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, frequency,
            channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    audioTrack.play();

    while (dis.available() > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while (dis.available() > 0 && i < audiodata.length) {
            audiodata[i] = dis.readShort();
            i++;
        }
        audioTrack.write(audiodata, 0, audiodata.length);
    }

    dis.close();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
}
```

I am new to short sample and byte samples. I tried to understand but it not so easy.

I could understand the first solution is using byte sample and the second solution is using short samples.

So why is the second solution not working.

Answer (score 0):

The default size of a `short` type is [two bytes](https://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/integer/integertypes). You might have a look at [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) as well.

The audio track has a recommended buffer size and sample rate which can be found using the way suggested here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317382/3145960). Please have a look.

However, it is important to play the audio using the recommended sample rate which is 44100 Hz in your case and the recommended buffer size that you get using the following code segment.

```
AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding)
```

In your implementation with `short` array, the buffer size is doubled and hence its creating noises in case of playing the audio. I would suggest, you might consider changing the buffer size by dividing the size by two in your implementation using `short`.

```
short[] audiodata = new short[(int) bufferSize / 2];
```

Hope you have understood the problem.

Comment: How do you now buffer size is doubled. I tried buffersize/2 still the noise is there.

Comment: Can you please try with `bufferSize * 2` (i.e. doubling the buffer size)?

Comment: In case of taking the buffer size in short, I was referring to this tutorial [here](https://www.androidcookbook.info/application-development/playing-sound-with-audio-track.html). However, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25703580/3145960), it suggests to increase buffer size. Please look into the links that I have shared.